# I got a wipe stuck/ clogged in the Air-filter holes need helpful advice

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, maintenance, repair, air-filter

I was changing/cleaning out my Air filter inside my 2004 Chevy Classic and as i was cleaning it out i notice the box where the air filter gone was very dirty so i wiped it with a wipe and it fell inside the hole under the battery. is it easy to take out? I just recently got the car and can't affordable any high in cost for repairs and mad at myself for allowing the wipe to fall inside the hole of the air filter. Can someone share any advice on how to to solve this problem or have any recommendations on what tools to get so i can get to the bottom of this [image][image]

Comment: A photo would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

I'd try the following things:

1. Vacuum it out (imho the best solution, as you can also clean the air filter housing)
2. Use a flexible pickup tool (photo attached) and try not to lodge it deeper, as poking aimlessy will certainly be counterproductive
3. Remove the air filter housing and shake the wipe and remaining debris out.
   [image]